# How to run a specific script in a haml view?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, polling

So I'm trying to invoke a `pollServer();` script in a haml view but it's not running.  Here's how:

```
    %div{:id => 'ajaxurl', :class => @poll.id}
  :javascript
    $(document).ready(function(){
      pollServer();
    });
```

**Here's the pollServer function:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
  console.log('here i am');
  function pollServer(){
    console.log('enter pollServer');
    setInterval(function(){
      console.log('enter setInterval');
      var id = $('div#ajaxurl').attr('class');
      $.ajax({
        // Div class dynamically set to poll.id

        type: 'GET',  
        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/polls/' + id, 
        complete: function(data){
          console.log('pollServer complete');
          updateSurvey(data);
        },
        success: function(data){
          console.log('pollServer success');
          updateSurvey(data);
        },  
        error: function(){
          console.log('pollServer error');
        }


      });
    }, 4000);
  };
});
```

Here's the PollsController's show action that handles the request:

```
  def show
    @poll = Poll.find(params[:id])


    # using for showTotalVotes
    gon.votes = @poll.questions[0].answers.map{|answer| answer.votes}

    # gon.poll_ids = @poll.questions[0].answers.map{|answer| answer.id}
    gon.titles = @poll.questions[0].answers.map{|answer| answer.title}
    # gon.poll_data = [gon.poll_ids, gon.titles , gon.votes ]
    # =>  gon.answer = @poll.questions[0].answers


    # gon.poll_hash = @poll.questions[0].answers.map{|answer| answer = {:id=> answer.id, :title => answer.title, :votes => answer.votes} }  

    @question = @poll.questions[0]
    @answers = @question.answers
    gon.answers = @poll.questions[0].answers

    respond_to do |format|

      format.html { @poll}

      format.js {
        render json: gon.answers 
      }
    end
```

The weird thing is, is that my server log actually polls my rails server and shows the sql db queries correctly retrieving data at the specified ajax path, but it won't console.log('hi') nor does it invoke the updateSurvey method on ajax success.  Any ideas why this might be happening?

**Update**

**Here's the updateSurvey function that pollServer function should be invoking**

```
  function updateSurvey(all_data){
    console.log('balls');
    var svg = d3.select('svg')
    var bars = svg.selectAll('rect')
        .data(all_data)
        .transition()
        .duration(500)
        .attr("y", function(d){
          return h + (yOffset - yScale(d.votes))
            // return h-(d.votes*10); 
        })
        .attr("height", function(d){
          barHeight = yScale(d.votes);
          return barHeight;
        })  
  }
```

Comment: If you'r source code is exactly as above then it does not log 'hi' because you wrote console.log(hi) so it would try to log variable. All following js may not run as well then.

Comment: I'm also pretty sure you should pass function name to setInterval, not anonymous function. Instead I would write `$(document).ready(function(){
      setInterval(pollServer, 4000);
    });`

Comment: Ok, some googling and I was obviously wrong about anonymous functions. Still your code above is not logging hi. Rest of it looks ok.

Comment: Cool, thanks for the tip! changed the (hi) to ('hi') but it's still not invoking the updateSurvey function.  This app is behaving really weirdly...

Comment: Is your server returning proper content type? When I tested it against google I needed to change `success` to `complete` to get `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: updateSurvey`

Comment: Please add controller code, the problem is there!

Answer (score 1):

I think you server is returning json with improper content type.
I run this code:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function pollServer(){

  setInterval(function(){
    console.log('hi');
    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET', 
      dataType: 'json',
      url: 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&sensor=true', 
      success: function(data){
        console.log('hi');
        updateSurvey(data);
      }
    });
  }, 4000);
};

$(document).ready(function()
  pollServer();
});
</script>
```

And get

```
hi
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: updateSurve
```

That would explain both - why js code is not run and SQL on server side is.

Comment: Interesting, how did you run it though?  I have the updateSurvey function in another file.  If you ran the code without it(I'll post it in a sec) that might be why it couldn't find it.  Because I don't get that error(or any error at all) when I render the views that trigger the scripts.

Comment: Take look at this comment - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17112601/how-to-run-a-specific-script-in-a-haml-view/17114549?noredirect=1#comment24762478_17112601

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the help!  It's definitely leading towards the right solution, but it still doesn't enter the function call.  For instance, in the updated pollServer it only console logs "here I am"  I'm thinking because the app is still retrieving info from the server every four seconds, despite not entering THAT pollServer, it must be getting invoked somewhere else in the app somehow.

Comment: Try adding a `complete` block to ajax and see if you get a response in there. YOu shoud be able to catch errors if any in there